# why 'overflow' is not working correctly on mobile?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I have problem scrolling with touch scrolling, it's working just fine with mouse and keyboard arrows but not by touching.
This is the html code:

```
<div class="drive-dashboard">
   <div id="dashboardContainer" class="dashboard-container"/>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS part

```
.drive-dashboard {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Any suggestions where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before and in React i've been able to solve it with something like:

```
`document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {}, true);`
```

But, I have to admit sometimes i've needed to use it and sometimes not, so I am not sure which html elements respond and which don't.

[Here is some reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_touchstart.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The weird part that everything works perfectly when i disable javascript